# Weird Behavior using gcc and glib?

Tags: c, gcc, glib

It only prints the description when I print b again after the if statement, really weird behavior, when I remove the last line it doesn't print `description is ...`dos anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this? Thanks

```
char * b;
if (list!= NULL){
b = strdup ( (char *)g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(list->data), "description") );
printf(" description is %s ", b);
}
printf("\nprinting b: %s\n", b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems `stdout` is line-buffered, i.e. `printf` hoards output until it encounters a newline or its buffer fills up. Add a newline to the first `printf`:

```
printf(" description is %s\n", b);
```

To *ensure* the output buffer is flushed, you can say:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also flush the buffer any time with fflush()